# Visual Studio Add Service Reference error

Tags: visual-studio, service, reference, addition

When I try to 'Add Service Reference' to my Visual Studio 2010 web page I get the following error:
`'Could not resolve mscorlib for target framework '.NETFramework, version=v4.0'. This can happen if the target framework is not installed or if the framework moniker is incorrectly formatted'`

This started after some Windows updates, prior to this I have added web services to web pages without any issue. Looking online I found someone with the same problem mention an apostrophe in their name being the cause of the issue. My name (and Windows username) has an apostrophe in it, so to test this I created a new user without the apostrophe and logged in under that name, creating a web site in Visual Studio where I was able to 'Add Service Reference' without the error. Can anyone suggest why this might be happening and suggest a fix for me?

For reference, I am running Windows 7 professional 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - if your project resides in a folder with metacharacters (like quotes), then Bad Things can happen :)

Frankly, having a Windows username with a quote isn't a very good idea.

But just move your project to a directory that DOESN'T have any metacharacters, and you should be fine.

Comment: Just odd that it has worked fine for over a year before the updates